# Thymeleaf Layout dont display

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I was trying to implement  thymeleaf layout using LayoutDialect with this  quide : http://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-spring-layouts

I think that I proceed all steps correctly, but the page blanc is display.
When I remove  setting Dialect in WebConfiguration,  the "content" is showing, but with this dialect, when i debug sources: it contains only line

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Where it could be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

you need configurate you WebConfiguration like:

```
<bean id="templateResolver"
    class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/templates/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
</bean>

<bean id="groupingStrategy"
    class="nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.decorators.strategies.GroupingStrategy" />

<bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="additionalDialects">
        <set>
            <bean class="nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.LayoutDialect">
                <constructor-arg ref="groupingStrategy" />
            </bean>
        </set>
    </property>
    <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
</bean>
```